# Limit Gesture Sensitivity on Ginn

Tags: touchpad, workspaces, multi-touch, mint, magic-trackpad

I installed ginn, and set it up so when I do a left or right four finger swipe, it sends the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd> (direction) key press to easily move between workspaces. It works, but it keeps on sending the key press, so when I make the gesture once, the workspace moves four to five times. Is there a way to change the sensitivity of the gesture, or only send the key press once the gesture is complete?

I tried messing with the `wishes.xml` file in `/usr/share/`, but it didn't help much.

This is my configuration that controls the four finger swipe

```
<wish gesture="Drag" fingers="4">
  <action name="action3" when="finish">
    <trigger prop="delta x" min="300" max="600"/>
    <key modifier1="Control_L" modifier2="Alt_L">Left</key>
  </action>
</wish>
<wish gesture="Drag" fingers="4">
  <action name="action4" when="finish">
    <trigger prop="delta x" min="-600" max="-300"/>
    <key modifier1="Control_L" modifier2="Alt_L">Right</key>
  </action>
```